# How to record the user action into table on Laravel Livewire?

Tags: laravel, livewire-3

I have the following middleware to record the user action into the user_action_logs table.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Models\UserAccessLog;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class UserAccess
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $user_id = null;
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        }

        $now = Carbon::now()
            ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        UserAccessLog::create([
            UserAccessLog::USER_ID => $user_id,
            UserAccessLog::IP_ADDRESS => $request->ip(),
            UserAccessLog::PATH => $request->path(),
            UserAccessLog::QUERY_STRING => $request->getQueryString(),
            UserAccessLog::DATE_AND_TIME => $now,
        ]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then let's see the table how the user action log is recorded.

```
> select * from user_access_logs;
+----+---------+--------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | ip_address   | path | query_string                                                 | date_and_time       |
+----+---------+--------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | NULL    | 192.168.65.1 | /    | keyword=engineer&philippine_province_ids%5B0%5D=0722&salary= | 2024-03-08 09:23:02 |
+----+---------+--------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Well, looked working fine.
But when I opened the page that includes livewire component, the following records were appeared.

```
|  6 | 9b8367e7-5f0c-414f-972c-ad37f98b7d0b | 192.168.65.1 | dashboard/personnel/applications | NULL         | 2024-03-08 09:37:51 |
|  7 | 9b8367e7-5f0c-414f-972c-ad37f98b7d0b | 192.168.65.1 | livewire/update                  | NULL         | 2024-03-08 09:38:19 |
```

The first record was that when I opened the page of livewire component.
The second one was that when I turn on the radio.
And after that any actions on the livewire component was recorded as '/livewire/update'.

OK, I have updated the middleware not to record '/livewire/update'.

```
        if ($request->path() !== 'livewire/update') {
            $now = Carbon::now()
                ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            UserAccessLog::create([
                UserAccessLog::USER_ID => $user_id,
                UserAccessLog::IP_ADDRESS => $request->ip(),
                UserAccessLog::PATH => $request->path(),
                UserAccessLog::QUERY_STRING => $request->getQueryString(),
                UserAccessLog::DATE_AND_TIME => $now,
            ]);
        }
```

But how can I record the operation on the livewire component in a smart way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to log all the requests and livewire does more that you formerly expected. So try to define "smart way" first.

Comment: Yes, I would like to record all the requests. I have many livewire components and to implement the functionality to record all the user action on all the livewire components are not smart.

It's the smartest way for me if I can implement the trait that can record the user actions and use its trait on livewire components.

Thank you for your feedback.